# IDA Pro: use structs on parameters

Tags: ida, struct

I have a small function that is given a `struct` as parameters. The `struct` looks to something like this:

```
struct my_struct {
  short a;
  unsigned int b;
  unsigned int c;
};
```

Taking care of the alignment I build the following `struct` in IDA:

```
field_0 +0x0
field_1 +0x4
field_2 +0x8
```

The compiler builds it so that it takes `rbp+0x10` as the first field in the `struct`, `rbp+0x14` as the second and so on. The problem now arises because if I try to apply the pre-defined IDA `struct` to the instructions, I always get something like `[rbp+struct.field_0+0x10]`. This get more complicated if there is actually something in my struct at `+0x10`, because then it just shows `[rbp+struct_fieldX]` (which is wrong).

The question is: *Is there a way to tell IDA (I'm using 6.3) to apply the `struct` with an offset of `0x10`?*

The dirty trick for this simple case is to create a `struct` that has 2 `size_t` dummy fields for the `RIP` and `SFP`, but that does not seem to be right way to go here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add your struct in the function's stack view:

1. With your cursor in the function's disassembly view, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to open the stack view.
2. In the stack view, ensure that enough function arguments exist to get to at least `+00000010` in the stack. Use <kbd>D</kbd> to add more function arguments as necessary.
3. Position your cursor on the `+00000010` line in the stack view and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to specify `my_struct` at that offset.

Comment: Note for emphasis: During step three, you **must** be on the stack view. If you place your cursor on the corresponding local variable in IDA view and press `Alt+Q`, IDA will try to interpret *the contents of the function* as a structure, rather than the variable, which destroys the function.  This is a mistake I see people make pretty often when learning structures in IDA.