# IDA: View stack frame variables

Tags: ida

In IDA, how can you view the stack frame for a local function *when IDA does not recognize any locals*? Normally this would be done by double clicking on a local, but there is no local to start with. It's also absent from the 'Open Subviews' menu.

Answer (score 9):

Although it doesn't appear to be documented anywhere (including in *The IDA Pro Book*) , I stumbled upon an answer: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. It was casually mentioned [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/ida-pro-use-structs-on-parameters).

It's also available in the menu Edit > Functions > Stack Variables

Comment: At least in my Ida 6.9, this is also accessible from the menu in Edit/Functions/Stack Variables.